# check for and close firefox popup with batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I have this simple batch script that opens up a firefox profile

```
@echo off

start firefox.exe -P default -no-remote
```

sometimes the profile is already opened and i get this popup.
[image]

Is there anyway to check if the popup appeared and click the close firefox button? Or maybe theres a piece of code where i can close the firefox profile and play that in the begining of the batch file so that i know for sure its closed and dont get that popup. Thanks for your help.

Comment: do you have any idea which button(s) to close the pop-up?

Comment: "Close Firefox" button

Comment: I've meant keyboard buttons :-D

Comment: `taskkill /im firefox.exe` will kill all firefoxes running. Only Internet Explorer is scriptable.

Comment: Perhaps [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/) or [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) would be more suitable for a task like this; pure batch scripting is bot capable of controlling windows or sending key strokes...

Answer (score 0):

Try with [sendkeys.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/sendKeys.bat):

```
call sendkeys.bat "Close Firefox" "{LEFT}{ENTER}"
```